# Website Facebook share show in carousel post format

Tags: facebook, carousel, facebook-opengraph, facebook-share

**Background**

Lately, Facebook added a "carousel" ad format, showing multiple slides in a sponsored post. This is now available for non-business users too.

[image: Facebook example of a carousel ad format]
*Facebook example of a carousel ad format*

**Meta annotation**

I am looking for a way to "annotate" my website in a way that it will be showing a carousel in a Facebook post when the url is used in a post. Currently I am using Open Graph (og) meta tags for annotation.

**HTML share link**

Besides that, I'm looking for a way to add multiple "carousel slides" to a Facebook share link. Currently I am using the following html for Facebook share links:

```
<a
    href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed
        ?app_id=123
        &link=http%3A%2F%2Fmy.url.com
        &picture=http%3A%2F%2Fmy.url.com/img.jpg
        &name=MyTitle
        &caption=MyCaption
        &description=MyDescription
        &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmy.url.com"
    target="_blank"
>
        Share on Facebook
</a>
```

Both ways result in the default post format. Can anyone help me with Facebook sharing in carousel format?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a feature that is being tested and it's not possible to apply for it.

Comment: Is it still being tested?

Answer (score 0):

Now this feature is live & when posting on a page select Image format and select carousal, you can add about 6 images to carousal & publish.